# dynamically select value from drop down list

Tags: javascript

I have the following drop down list:

```
<select name="selSS1" id="select_value">
    <option value="val0">sea zero</option>
    <option value="val1">sea one</option>
    <option value="val2">sea two</option>
    <option value="val3">sea three</option>
    <option value="val4">sea four</option>
</select>
```

I would like to dynamically select a value from that list using javascript:

I tried:

```
document.getElementById('select_value').selected ="val3";
```

But the above code does not seem to work. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: You have to be familiar with the Javascript methods and properties

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following line:

```
 document.getElementById('select_value').value ="val3";

or 

    document.getElementById('select_value').selectedIndex = 3;
```

Hope this solves ur problem.

Comment: well that code replaces the selected value it does not retrieve it, so the questions is wrong

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById('select_value');
mySelect.getElementsByTagName('option')[index].setAttribute('selected','selected');
```

where index stands for the position of the option you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#select_value').val('val0');
```

Answer (score 0):

With plain JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementById("select_value");
var selectedValue = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

`document.getElementById('select_value').option[3].selected;`

Answer (score 0):

THis will select val 3

```
document.getElementById('select_value').selectedIndex=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the selected one by the value, try this function. By declaring a function you will be able to use this functionality with any select :).

// Simplest version

```
function setSelected(select_id,value){

    document.getElementById(select_id).value = value;

}
```

// Or, complex version

```
function setSelected(select_id,value){

    var mySelect = document.getElementById(select_id);
    var options = mySelect.options;
    var key;
    for(key in options){

        if(options[key].value===value){
            options[key].setAttribute("selected","");
        }
        else
            options[key].removeAttribute("selected");
    }
}
```

in your case:

```
setSelected("select_value","val3");
```